# Why is compareTo() receiving runtime error when comparing two objects?

Tags: java, object, casting, polymorphism, compareto

When referencing the object "r2" at line 12, there is a runtime error. Why is this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Rational r1 = new Rational(-2, 6);
    System.out.println(r1.getNumerator());
    System.out.println(r1.getDenominator());
    System.out.println(r1.intValue());
    System.out.println(r1.doubleValue() + "\n");
    
    Object r2 = new Rational(1,45);
    System.out.println((r2).compareTo(r1));
    
}
```

In line 11, I changed the object class to Rational and the code works but it does not work with **Object r2**. I'm just curious as to the underlying reason this doesn't work with **Object r2**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what should happen if you try to compare an Object to a Rational, and you ask the Object class for the code that explains the comparison? Do Objects know how to be compared to Rationals? In your own words, if you write `(r2).compareTo(r1)`, and the **variable** `r2` has the type `Object`, what class do you think will be used to find the `compareTo` code? Why?

Comment: Hello. For future reference, when the question is about an error message, please include, as text, a copy of the error message in the question body. When the question references line numbers in the code, the question body should indicate which are the line numbers being referred to.  It may help to include, as text, example input and output.

Comment: First and foremost, ***never*** try to run code that doesn't compile, as you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object` does not declare a method with the name `compareTo`, thus you cannot call it. Typically, classes that provide a sorting order implement `Comparable`, so this is the type you should use for just a guarantee of being able to compare two objects.